# JointJS port positioning

Tags: javascript, jointjs

How do I get the ports at the top and bottom of a Model object?

I see that the ports are always created in the left and right of the model.  I need it on the top and bottom.

I do not want to use the rotate transformation as it changes the orientation of the labels too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution to that luckily

You have certain `Model object`, right? Let's call it as `element`.

```
element.attr({
'.inPorts': {transform: 'rotate(-90)'}
});
```

The ports will now be horizontally situated. Play a little with theor exact positioning.
You can use `ref-x` or `ref-y` property.

```
element.attr({
    '.inPorts': {transform: 'rotate(-90)', 'ref-x':0.3,'ref-y':-0.3}
});
```

**Note:** It only works for having ports on top of element, try some hack for bottom as well.

Happy Coding!